# Is there a framework for allowing apps published on Codeplex to auto-update directly from Codeplex?

Tags: .net, codeplex, auto-update

Endowing utility applications with "auto-update" capability seems like basic good manners these days.

I'm thinking of apps like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) or [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/download.html), that proactively tell you "hey, there's a newer release available. Wanna download it?"

**Q**: Does anyone know of a common framework that can be used by apps that come from Codeplex projects, to alert the user if there is a newer release, and optionally download and install that newer release directly from CodePlex?

Obviously there's [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx), and the [Updater Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978574.aspx), and I've written utility classes for doing this myself, for winforms and [WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/03/28/simple-auto-update-for-wpf-apps.aspx), and other people have written [similar things](http://autoupdatewpf.codeplex.com/), but all these require the app publisher to publish the app outside of Codeplex, in order for the auto-update to work.  What I'm imagining is something that just downloads directly from codeplex.

---

**EDIT**
I can imagine such a framework might impose a structure on how the app is published to codeplex.  It may require a "manifest.xml" to be published with each release, and inside that manifest file might be a app version, timestamp, notes on the release, URL to the latest binary download, and so on.

It seems like someone would have built this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all I know (based on my experience of trying to make [Componento](http://www.componento.net/) download archives from CodePlex), it is notoriously difficult to just donwload a single file programmatically, since constructing a link similar to `http://mef.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=34838#DownloadId=88937` is not a very plesant experience.

That said, it's still possible to have a single 'updates.xml` file at a well-known location and check for updates using it.

Comment: I was thinking a common framework would parse the RSS feed for releases, then look for a well-known name (like "manifest.xml") on each release. . .

Answer (score 1):

Codeplex does support auto-updateable releases with the ClickOnce Setup projects. They have a [FAQ, including that topic](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ClickOnce&referringTitle=Releases).

I have done that myself, look at http://replayer.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

http://codeplex.codeplex.com/Services/SourceControlService.asmx?op=GetModificationsForDateRange

They have a good enough SOAP API these days, apparently.

Comment: There also is a "release" endpoint, here `https://www.codeplex.com/Services/ReleaseService.asmx?op=GetRelease`, that could be used to fetch update information.